# Create an array of categories but exclude "include in navigation" = OFF categories

Tags: php, magento

the following code creates an array of categories. How can I only get the categories which are set to "include in navigation" = ON

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    if (! isset($this->_options))
    {
        $options = array(
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vertnav')->__('Store base'),
                'value' => 'root',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vertnav')->__('Current category children'),
                'value' => 'current',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vertnav')->__('Same level as current category'),
                'value' => 'siblings',
            ),
        );
        $resource = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getResource();
        $select = $resource->getReadConnection()->select()->reset()
            ->from($resource->getTable('catalog/category'), new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(`level`)'));
        $maxDepth = $resource->getReadConnection()->fetchOne($select);
        for ($i = 2; $i < $maxDepth; $i++)
        {
            $options[] = array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vertnav')->__('Category Level %d', $i),
                'value' => $i,
            );
        }
        $this->_options = $options;
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

public function getAllOptions()
{
    return $this->toOptionArray();
}
```

This code is part of an navigation extension which creates an vertical navigation for
categories in magento. But unfortunately it shows all categories regardless if they are set to "include in navigation" = ON or OFF.

Hope someone can give me a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that should work

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu' , 1)
->addAttributeToSort('level' , 'DESC');

$maxDepth = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getLevel();
```

The key here is the filter on attribute `include_in_menu` which will search only through categories that have the Include in menu option set to Yes.
Then sort by level from greater to lower and get the first one with `getFirstItem()` method.

No perf issue thanks to magento easy loading mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to insert the filder [code]->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu' , 1)
[code] in the extension and finaly it works like we thought :)